# Set focus to a Silverlight control from javascript

Tags: silverlight

I'm having a focus issue with Silverlight...

How can I set the focus to my Silverlight control using javascript?

Comment: This should be part of the standard things that comes with Silverlight, but they had to allow for the default where Silverlight was just used for banners etc (which don't take focus).

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to your Silverlight hosting page (just above the onSilverlightError function):

```
function appLoad(sender, args) {
    var xamlObject = document.getElementById('SilverlightObject');
    if (xamlObject != null)
        xamlObject.focus();
}
```

In the object declaration itself (e.g. in `<object id='SilverlightObject'`) add this  after `<param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />`:

```
    <param name="onLoad" value="appLoad" />
```

Also make sure the object names match (in this case 'SilverlightObject')

Comment: So simple but I didn't find it myself. Many thanks. Should be marked as correct solution.

Comment: Do you know what browsers work with this code?  For me, it seems to work with IE9, but not Opera.