# Adding a dependency property to a text box

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, dependency-properties

How can I Add a dependency property to a text box and bind the dependency property to a Boolean property in silver light. my Boolean property is in my view model.

ImageSearchIsFocused is the property which allows me to set the focus on a text box.

```
<TextBox  Text="{Binding ImgSearch, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">   
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <common:FocusBehavior HasInitialFocus="True" IsFocused="{Binding ImageSearchIsFocused, Mode=TwoWay}" ></common:FocusBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

ImageIsFocused Property

```
bool _ImageSearchIsFocused;
public bool ImageSearchIsFocused
{
    get { return _ImageSearchIsFocused; }
    set
    { 
        _ImageSearchIsFocused = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSearchIsFocused");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the dependency property you want to add? Your example only shows an attached behavior. Can you show your code (e.g. for the behavior?)

Comment: @HiTech Magic This is what Im following http://jklogic.blogspot.com/2012/02/silverlight-setting-focus-to-text-box.html

Comment: That helps. What does the code for your ImageSearchIsFocused property look like?

Comment: Is this happening at app-startup by any chance? If so, your Silverlight app does not get focus by default, so the control focus will not be visible without extra work like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107460/set-focus-to-a-silverlight-control-from-javascript/4107503#4107503

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dependency property, you're going to have the subclass the TextBox and add the dependency property to your subclass.  Then you can bind that to whatever you like:

```
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{ 

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyBooleanValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyBooleanValue", typeof(bool), typeof(MyTextBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(MyBooleanValueChanged)));
    public bool MyBooleanValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(MyBooleanValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyBooleanValueProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void MyBooleanValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var propValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        var control = d as MyTextBox;

        // do something useful
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't have to subclass a TextBox it to add a new dependency property to one. You can add any new DependencyProperty to any DependencyObject derived class, so long as the typeof matches.